# How to reorder rows in a table SQL

Tags: sql, postgresql

just wondering how to reorder rows in this table? I want to have 2015 through 2019 ASCENDING as `happiness_rank` increases, but 2015 automatically goes to the bottom of the table.

I have tried using

```
UPDATE table_name ORDER BY happiness_rank;
```

but that doesn't work, and similarly `ALTER TABLE` doesn't seem to work either. I know I can do it with `SELECT` but that doesn't save the table, and when I try to do `UPDATE` with `SELECT` and `ORDER BY` it doesn't work.

| h_score | happiness_rank | economy_gdp_per_capita |
| --- | --- | --- |
|  | 2 | 1.52733 |
|  | 4 | 1.56497955322266 |
|  | 5 | 1.420 |
|  | 6 | 1.452 |
| 2015 | 1 | 1.39651 |

Comment: Why would you want to do that if you can output the desired result with SELECT ?

Comment: The order of rows is generally managed through the order of the underlying _clustered_ index, but even this can get fragmented, so when querying the data with a `SELECT` statement, we ignore the underlying order and specify the specific order that we want to access the data in.

Comment: A request to manipulate the underlying storage sequence generally indicates a misunderstanding of how SQL works. Please elaborate only _WHY_ you think you want to change the order of the records as they are stored.

Comment: Rows in a table have no orders, so you can't "reorder" them. Use an `ORDER BY` when you _select_ the data

Comment: What is the primary key in this table? It would be great if you can share the entire schema along with the Data Type and Is Nullable information.

Answer (score 1):

SELECT query is always used while reading table, so the info about how your tables is stored in SQL is pointless to you. If I am missing something, please tell me as even during export - you will use SELECT query.

Answer (score 0):

You can do one of the following according to your needs:

1. If your table does not have any Indexes or Foreign Keys then simply use `ALTER`

   ```
   ALTER TABLE tablename ORDER BY happiness_rank ASC;
   ```

However, it does not make sense to order them on insert. I wouldn't do this. (Not Recommended)

2. Add a new column with datatype integer which is sorted ASC and set it as the primary key. Usually, this is the column that has some unique ID and is an auto-generated sequence. (Recommended)